# Email notification configuration problem on GLPI

Tags: php, config, open-source

Please someone could explain me what's wrong with this GLPI configuration I tried everything it doesn't work I understand nothing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used my outlook account it worked I think of a block due to the security of GMAIL if you get there with let me know thank you.